# Apply 1D function to 2D space

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 2d, gaussian

This may be a better question for the Mathematics Stack Exchange, so let me know if that is the case.

I'm doing some analysis on 2D image matrices that have a fairly Gaussian shape: [image: Sample image]

I wrote a simple MATLAB function for getting at a rough approximation of the 1D Gaussian fit of any particular row/column "slice" of this data:

```
function [fit,a,b,c] = getgauss(slice)

    q = 1:length(slice);
    b = find(slice==max(slice));
    a = slice(b);
    temp = gradient(slice);
    c1 = find(temp==max(temp));
    c2 = find(temp==min(temp));
    c = round(mean([c2-b b-c1]));
    fit = a.*exp(-((q-b).^2)./(2*c^2));
    clear c1 c2 q temp

end
```

My question is how do I turn this into a 2D "fit" instead? Do I do just run this over every row and column and then do some kind of cross-multiplication?

It seems there is a Curve Fitting Toolbox in MATLAB that I cannot afford unfortunately. Any tips?

Comment: Are you asking about the mathematical procedure to do the 2D fit?

Comment: You should probably be doing some form of MLE (maximum likelihood estimation) since you know the shape of the [function that describes your data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Two-dimensional_Gaussian_function). This question could possibly fit [stats.se] too...